# Unable to connect to website using FTP software

Tags: ftp, website, winscp

I recently made this post over on the WinSCP forums and was encouraged to post here to try and solve the issue, so this is a copy and paste of an existing thread:

A a few days ago I updated a theme on my WordPress website (http://mmgaming.net/) and now trying to access it results in a syntax error. This was the same for trying to log in to the admin section. So I learn that to solve this, I need to access the site using FTP.

First I tried FileZilla on my work Mac, but was repeatedly getting a 510 Mismatch error every time I tried to log-in. Some checking around online (https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=35311) suggests that this is an issue with Firewalls and not using "Active Mode" on FileZilla (something I didn't know how to set up).

So now I've switched to my home PC and am trying to use WinSCP, as I was hoping it was just my work network that was the problem. First I was getting a time out issue of:

```
Timeout detected. (control connection)
```

So then I found a thread saying to turn on Active Mode and to try and and extend the amount of time that it takes to connect. So I unchecked Passive Mode and changed the server response timeout to 30 seconds. This then resulted in a new error:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I am at a complete loss and have no idea what to do or try next. Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks in advance!

(P.s. I've seen a few posts here posting Logs and so-on, but I don't actually know where to find those/how to get them, so if those would be useful please let me know how to get them.)

Comment: What is your website's hosting company, and have they provided you with the FTP connection details or are you going by trial-and-error? In fact, does your hosting company even provide FTP access?

Comment: I actually might have to get back to you about that. I'm moderately certain that it's hosted by WordPress though (it's a WordPress website but we briefly had it externally hosted for a while). Also, I was just trying to connect directly to the website with my Admin login details. Is that the wrong way to go about that?

Comment: Our previous host was TsoHost.

Comment: FTP is different than HTTP and generally also has different login information for extra security. You'll need to contact your host to see how to connect. The "welcome" letter you probably got when you signed up should have the information as well. Are you currently hosted with wordpress.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to solve this, I need to access the site using FTP.

This might be true, but **websites do not automatically have FTP access.** FTP is a separate service that the hosting provider needs to have set up – with accounts independent from your website, and the server address quite possibly different from the website's name.

So while most "shared web hosting" companies do provide FTP access automatically (and/or SFTP, more recently), it is not guaranteed to be there; and even if it is there, you might be connecting to the wrong server or using the wrong credentials.

And in fact if the WordPress installation was done by the hosting company, then it's more likely that you *won't* have direct access to the files at all. (In this case, actually, isn't the company supposed to be fixing such problems as well?)

> I'm moderately certain that it's hosted by WordPress

No; it uses the WordPress *software* but is not hosted through WordPress.com – it is a custom installation on some other company's servers. (Signs point to "UK Webhosting Ltd" and/or "Paragon Internet Group Ltd".)

> I was just trying to connect directly to the website with my Admin login details.

That is unlikely to work.

If you installed WordPress on your own, then its accounts are completely independent from FTP accounts or other kinds of "control panel" accounts.

If WordPress was installed by the hosting company – *if* you're on some kind of "WordPress and nothing else" plan – then there's a *slight* chance they'll be identical... but it's far more likely that you don't actually have FTP access whatsoever.

Comment: >"websites do not automatically have FTP access." 
Oh really? Dang. When I first Googled the syntax error most of the things I discovered suggested I needed to use an FTP and so I assumed it would be pretty straightforward to connect... Bugger.

>"it is a custom installation on some other company's servers." 
I see. That's actually kind of weird because we don't pay for hosting.

>"it's far more likely that you don't actually have FTP access whatsoever." 
Right, so presumably the next step for me should in fact be to try and get in touch with whoever is actually hosting the site?

Comment: May I also ask how you deduced where the site might be hosted? If everything comes down to that, it might be that we're not 100% sure where we're hosted.

Comment: WHOIS on the web server's IP address shows it as being owned by the company mentioned earlier. If it were hosted on the 'official' WordPress.com platform, it would have shown Automattic, Inc as the server location (and you certainly _wouldn't_ have FTP access to that, nor would you ever get the kind of error message that you do now).

Comment: Right, so it looks like somehow the site is still hosted by TsoHost, even though we stopped paying that years ago! Well, I guess that gives me the next step, which is to contact them directly. I'll stick a correct answer on your post, but feel like I might have to necro if things continue to be difficult.